# Knockout.js newby needing some assistance

Tags: javascript, php, sorting, knockout.js

I have been fiddling with KO.js, I have downloaded x7Chat but there's a lot to finish in order for the Chat to fit my needs. One thing is the Online list, which is a list of Users that is online in the main chat room.

Administrators should be on top and have a different style sheet on their name-tag so that people knows that these are Admins. Now, in the database all admins have a value set to "1" in the row named "group_id" while all other users have the value set to "0" now the problem is that I'm not very good with ko.js, PHP is something I know more about.

Here's the Online list HTML code:

```
                <div id="onlinelist" data-bind="foreach: active_room().users()">
                <?php if($access_acp) { ?>
                    <div id="show_user_profile" class="onlineuser" data-bind="click: $root.show_user_profile"><a href='#' data-bind="text: group_id"></a></div>
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <div id="start_private_chat" class="onlineuser" data-bind="click: $root.start_private_chat"><a href='#' data-bind="text: user_name"></a></div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
```

I understand that I need to give you guys more code so I will post a link below for the full code of this file, thanks for the help!
http://pastebin.com/nwdPebHX

// FiNCH
**EDIT**
I'll try it! I have another problem that I've struggling with... I want the group_id in the database to be a value just as the user_id is in Javascript. I can't seem to get it to work! I've added this where I think it should be As you can see I added the group_id to that function, but it wont give me the value from the database, there MUST be a PHP file providing the information but I've looked for hours and cant fint it... Any ideas?

```
this.UserRoom = function(user) {
    this.user_id = user.user_id;
    this.room_id = user.room_id;
    this.group_id = user.group_id;
    this.user_name = acceptSwedish(user.user_name);
    this.refreshed = 1;
}
```

Comment: I can explain everything to you in pseudo-code if that is okay? The easiest way to distinguish between admins and normal users is to give admins a special colour. Would you like a pseudo-code explanation?

Comment: Thanks Joe, but llya seems to have this under control, cheers!

Comment: I see that he/she does. No problem :)

Answer (score 0):

For example if you want to set different `css` to admin and regular user, you can use [css binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html):
**CSS**

```
.admin
{
   color: red;
}
```

**View**

```
<div id="start_private_chat" 
     class="onlineuser" 
     data-bind="click: $root.start_private_chat, css: {admin : group_id() == 1}">
   <a href='#' data-bind="text: user_name"></a>
</div>
```

Or  [style binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/style-binding.html)

```
<div id="start_private_chat" 
     class="onlineuser" 
     data-bind="click: $root.start_private_chat, style: {color : group_id() == 1 ? 'red' : 'black'}">
   <a href='#' data-bind="text: user_name"></a>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**
You can divide all users on two groups with `ko.utils.arrayFilter` function e.g.

```
<div id="onlinelist" 
     data-bind="foreach: ko.utils.arrayFilter(active_room().users(), function(user)
                                              {
                                                 return user.group_id() === 1;   
                                              })">
  <!-- show admins -->
</div>
<!-- separator -->
<div id="onlinelist" 
     data-bind="foreach: ko.utils.arrayFilter(active_room().users(), function(user)
                                              {
                                                 return user.group_id() === 0;   
                                              })">
  <!-- show regular users -->
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, thanks! But how can I sort the list so that the Admins always are on TOP of the list?

Comment: Thanks, but I can't get it to work.. I tried changing group_id to user_id just to see if the code coulden't get the group_id value. But nothing I try seems to work, it accepts the code but there's nothing showing upp in the Onlinelist.

Comment: @user2965339 oh, sorry. I forgot `return` statement in `ko.utils.arrayFilter` callback. Answer is edited

Comment: I added an answer with another problem regarding this.